# Get 404 error When trying to fetch data from Node.js in React.js While server is running

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am not familiar with back-end and it is the first time to try it out.
Techset is React.js, Node.js, express.js, and mysql.
I want to request result of a query but 404 error occurs.
This is the code.

In React.js

```
    const resident_name = 'sss';
    let rates = [];

    async function getData(){
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({name: {resident_name}}),
        });
        rates = await res.result;
    };
    getData();
```

I want to execute the function as soon as the page that has it shows up.

In Node.js

```
app.post("/", (req,res)=>{
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  console.log("i got "+req.body.name);

  db.query(`SELECT r.* 
    FROM rate r INNER JOIN resident rs on r.resident_id = rs.resident_id 
    WHERE rs.name = ${req.body.name}`, (err,result)=>{
      // result is an array that contains dictionaries.
      if(err) throw err;

      result.forEach(r => {
        console.log(r)
      });

      res.send(result)
  });
});
```

I am not sure what causes the error. Can I plz get solution if you guys know some info about it?
Thank you!

- Edited: I am running both React.js on port 3000 and Node.js on port 3001. Once I type node index.js, I can see Server is listening to 3001 message on server-side console with this code below.

```
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Result on the console:
Server listening on 3001

I'm working on making sure the server is running in the way the first answer suggested.

Comment: Is your Express app actually listening on port 3001? Also, you probably meant `{name: resident_name}`

Comment: Yes. Port is 3001 and resident_name is a variable. that is why I used {}.

Comment: Where are you seeing the 404 response? If it's in your browser dev-tools, exactly what URL is the request for?

Comment: looks like this error mean your db didn't found the resident_name you search, so it throw error in your callback, are you sure in your db you have name with "sss" ?

Answer (score 0):

- first, make sure your server's API endpoint is correct and running.
- For that, you    can use Vs code extension like Thunder client by
  passing your port.
- And check for any network issue using `ping` command or firewall
  block.
- Also, check your header request or use tool like `curl`. In
  react.js while request from server, CORS also block to make request
  on the browser (as i have face same issue on past). So, make sure you
  check the server logs.

Answer (score -2):

404 error occurs only if there is nothing is listening in the mentioned address:`port`.

> Make sure you are requesting to the correct url with correct port number in which your express app is running.

Express app defaults to port 3000

Comment: But the client which means React.js is running on 3000. so I assigned the different number.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).